# how can I get the latest data in mysql with multiple records

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table that has a dates on every record and what im trying to do is get the latest base on the date of course. the table has a unique id that is equivalent to id from another table

here is an example:

record # 1 has the date of `2016/11/11`
record # 2 has the date of `2016/11/16`

obviously record number 2 is the latest data, when i try to use this code:

```
select * from 
info join crew_documents_table on info.id = crew_documents_table.document_crew_id 
join crew_rank on info.crew_rank = crew_rank.crew_rank_id 
where crew_rank in ('1','2','3') 
and crew_status = '$crew_status' and vessel = '$vessel_name' group by full_name
```

after i get the latest record i have here a `if statement` that will echo out the date of the latest record.

here is my code for my `if statement`

```
 (($row['doc_type'] == '1') ? "$doc_number" : "")
```

expected outpu will be:

`record # 2 2016/11/16`

Comment: Have you tried adding ORDER BY?

Comment: i only want the output 1 only. thanks for the tip

Comment: order by date desc limit 1

Comment: ORDER BY <field_name> DESC  LIMIT 1

Answer (score 1):

Use Order by and Limit. This would solve your problem:

```
select * from 
info join crew_documents_table on info.id = crew_documents_table.document_crew_id 
join crew_rank on info.crew_rank = crew_rank.crew_rank_id 
where crew_rank in ('1','2','3') 
and crew_status = '$crew_status' and vessel = '$vessel_name' group by full_name
ORDER BY DATE_FIELD DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use order by clause to get the data in specific order like:

```
$your_query. "order by column_name desc LIMIT 1";
```

[Limit Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)